# In Sage, how to extract coefficient of a polynomial in a ring

Tags: math-software, sagemath

For instance, $f=x^2y^2+1$ is an element of $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$, I want to extract the coefficient of $x^2$, which is $y^2$. However "f.coefficient(x,2)" only works for symbolic expressions, are there similar functions for ring elements?

Comment: I don't know anything about Sage, but perhaps you could tell it to find $\dfrac{1}{2}\dfrac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x^2}(0,y)$?

Comment: By the way, there http://ask.sagemath.org/ for sage. In case you have more specific questions in the future.

Answer (score 5):

Simply use `f.coefficient(x^2)`, as in this example:

```
sage: R.<x,y> = CC[]
sage: f = x^2 *  y^2 + 1
sage: f.coefficient(x^2)
y^2
```